# SQL insert use subquery result in another subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I am trying to run the following query in postgresql to insert data to a table from the subquery results of two tables.

Here are my three sample tables -

```sql
CREATE TABLE a (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
  data int
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE b (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  aID INT 
  data INT
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE c (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  aID INT,
  bID INT,
  name VARCHAR
);
```

I'm using the following query to do an INSERT into the `c` table -

```sql
INSERT INTO c (
  aID,
  bID,
  name)
VALUES (
  (SELECT id FROM a WHERE data=$1),
  (SELECT id FROM b WHERE data=$2 AND aID=(SELECT id FROM a WHERE data=$1)),
  $3)
ON CONFLICT (bID)
DO NOTHING;
```

I was wondering whether it was possible to use the results of the first `SELECT` from the `a` table in the second subquery to reduce data access. I'm not sure this is the right way to go. Any help  would be appreciated.

Comment: Removed the SQL Server and MySQL tags since you stated you are using PostgreSQL.

Comment: @BJones Thanks. I thought this was a generic sql question hence those tags.

Comment: The subquery in the second query is not the same as in the first, since it filters on `a.data = $2`. Is this a typo?

Comment: @GMB nope, that's intentional.

Comment: @GMB can you check my latest edit. Actually, that's what i want. So can you please modify your answer?

Comment: `c.aID` and `c.bID` are not defined `NOT NULL`. Nor is there a `UNIQUE` constraint or similar on `c.bID` (which contradicts `ON CONFLICT (bID)`). Omissions in the setup I assume? If `c.bID` is UNIQUE after all, consider a simplified relational design ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yeah, i just wanted to give an idea of the setup. I do have proper constraints and indexes with NOT NULL in the real setup.

Comment: Matters for the correct answer. (The currently accepted answer is not 100 % equivalent to your original in case of missing values.) Also, the setup makes it look like you can replace the whole table `c` with an additional column `b.c_name`. `ON CONFLICT (bID)`indicates there can be at most *one* entry per `bID` anyway ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering whether it was possible to use the results of the first SELECT from the a table in the second subquery to reduce data access.

I suspect that you want a `join` instead:

```
INSERT INTO c (aID, bID, name)
SELECT a.id, b.id, $3
FROM a 
INNER JOIN b ON b.aid = a.id
WHERE a.data = $1 AND b.data = $2
```

This assumes that the "first select from the a table" and the "second subquery" are actually the same query (which is not exactly the case in your question where the first query filters on `a.data = $1` while the subquery filters on `a.data = $2`). If the queries are different, then you are probably better off with two indenpendent queries).

Comment: Let me try this! Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Sorry, that second filter on `a.data = $1` was a typo. Thanks for the response. I'll use this query and let you know how it goes!